# removing vowels from array

Tags: java, arrays

The instructions >>
Implement the method named `removeVowels` which processes the array of strings named `words` by printing each string from `words` with only non-vowels on its own line.

For example, if words contains:

```java
{"every", "nearing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"}
```

The method should output:

```
vry
nrng
chckng
fd
stnd
vl
```

So far, I have:

```java
public class U6_L3_Activity_Two {
  public static void removeVowels(String[] hit_str) {
    char vowels = {
      'a',
      'e',
      'i',
      'o',
      'u',
      'A',
      'E',
      'I',
      'O',
      'U'
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < hit_str.length; i++) {
      if (find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(),
          hit_str[i]) != vowels.end()) {
        hit_str = hit_str.replace(i, 1, "");
        i -= 1;
      }
    }
    return hit_str;
  }
}
```

Runner:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class runner_U6_L3_Activity_Two
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter array length:");
    int len = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    String[] wordList = new String[len];
    System.out.println("Enter values:");
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      wordList[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }
    U6_L3_Activity_Two.removeVowels(wordList);
  }
}
```

The error message i'm getting says:

```
U6_L3_Activity_Two.java:3: error: illegal initializer for char
char vowels = {
^
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to make a list of vowels but none of them seem to work.

Comment: You're declaring `vowels` to be a single `char`. It needs to be an aary of characters, i.e. `char[]`

Comment: You should also read a tutorial on arrays https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing vowels with this built-in method:

```
String[] hit_str = { "every", "nearing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value" };

for (String str : hit_str) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", ""));
}
```

Here, the `for` loop iterates over your input string/s and uses `Regex` to check if char(s) is/are found from the provided `Regex`. `[AaEeIiOoUu]` tries to match all chars of `Regex` individually in the string chars. Using `Regex` is better than declaring a `char[]` as it improves code readability and saves us from writing complex logics.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it is not very useful imho, because there is no explanation of what is going on. It uses regex, which is a bit more involved that the basic character logic the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

There're many way to do this. I reccomen to split 2 tasks: remove vowels and print the results.

```java
private static final Pattern VOWELS = Pattern.compile("(?i)[aeiou]");

public static String[] removeVowels(String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words)
                 .map(word -> VOWELS.matcher(word).replaceAll(""))
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
```

In case you are **able to modife** the original array, you can avoid creation of the new one.

```java
public static String[] removeVowels(String[] words) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        words[i] = VOWELS.matcher(words[i]).replaceAll("");

    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

This looks like a college class task.  So, I'm going to answer assuming that you can't use more advanced data structures such as `List`, `Set`, etc.  I'm also going to assume that you can't box and unbox your primitives (i.e. change `int` to `Integer`).  If I recall from my college courses, the main point of these tasks is to learn to implement basic logic and loops.  This means you don't need to use advanced Java features such as `Pattern` and `Stream`.

This means that we need to stick with primitives, basic arrays, basic loops, and basic java functionality.  This also means that the code likely isn't going to be efficient, but it will meet the requirements of your course.

### Error Message

Your Error message says

> "illegal initializer for char"

You are trying to shove an array into a single character.  You can't do that.  Put some brackets after `char`, and your error message should go away.

```java
char[] vowels = {
      'a',
      'e',
      'i',
      'o',
      'u',
      'A',
      'E',
      'I',
      'O',
      'U'
    };
```

That being said, don't use this.  It's clunky and error prone.  There are better ways.

### Remove Vowels Method

That's not the only problem with your code though.  Your void method `removeVowels` has a return value.  void methods don't return anything.

#### Working through the task

Since the instructions say you have to receive an array of Strings, we know that your method, at a minimum, should look something like

```java
void removeVowels(String[] hit_str);
```

or

```java
String[] removeVowels(String[] hit_str);
```

Since you can modify the String array without having to pass it around, the void method should work fine.  So, now we can look at what the method should do.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
void removeVowels(String[] hit_str){
  for (int i = 0; i < hit_str.length; i++) {
    // if hit_str[i] contains a vowel, then remove it <-- Pseudo Code
  }
}
```

#### Fleshing out the Pseudo Code

At the point we hit the pseudo code, we know that hit_str[i] is a value within the array, and we know that it is a String.  Since String extends Java's Object, we know that it can be null.  We also know that `""` is a valid empty String.  We also know that `"cdf"` is also a valid String which doesn't contain any vowels.

So, we know that we should account for a null value in the array, as well as a value that has a length of 0, and a value that already matches our required criteria of no vowels.

So, our pseudo code now looks something like this

```java
// this could also be if (hit_str[i] != null ...
if (Objects.nonNull(hit_str[i]) && !hit_str[i].isEmpty()) {
  // remove vowels if they exist
}
```

#### Getting to work

Now that we finally have a String to work with, how do we remove the vowels from it.  Since our object is a String, java has a lot of methods to help us.  The best method would be `replaceAll`.

`replaceAll` uses a regex pattern to find any elements in the String that match the pattern, and replaces them with your designated replacement.  Our Regex would look like this `"(?i)[aeiou]"`.  It can be a bit confusing at first, but the elements in parentheses are the modifiers.  The `?` says match everything after, and the `i` means case insensitive.  The elements in the brackets are the elements to match.  So, this regex says to match everything in the string, case insensitive, against the letters in the brackets.

Example:

```java
String myString = "Look at all the vowels aeiou and AEIOU both upper and lower case";
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", ""));
```

This code produces `Lk t ll th vwls  nd  bth ppr nd lwr cs`.

#### Putting it together

So, our final code would look something like this.

```java
void removeVowels(String[] hit_str){
  for (int i = 0; i < hit_str.length; i++) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(hit_str[i]) && !hit_str[i].isEmpty()) {
      hit_str[i] = hit_str[i].replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", ""));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Using the method

Your `main` method should now look like this after the String[] array has been created.

```java
removeVowels(wordList);
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(wordList[i]);
}
```